# Pass method to a variable

Tags: java, methods

I'm doing a simple activity that will first generate 2 random cards. Now I already have a method for card1, but I want to copy this same method to card2 without copying it. Is there a way that I can reuse a certain method? 
This is the method:

```
            public static void Cards_Match(){
                 if(c1 >= 0 && c1 <=3)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[0];

                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 4 && c1 <=7)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[1];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 8 && c1 <=11)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[2];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 12 && c1 <=15)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[3];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 16 && c1 <=19)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[4];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 20 && c1 <=23)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[5];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 24 && c1 <=27)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[6];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 28 && c1 <=31)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[7];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 32 && c1 <=35)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[8];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 36 && c1 <=39)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[9];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 40 && c1 <=43)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[10];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 44 && c1 <=47)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[11];
                     }
                 else if(c1 >= 48 && c1 <=51)
                     {
                        card_rank = cards[12];
                     }

                 if(c1 % 4 == 0)
                     {
                        card_suit = suits[0];
                     }

                 else if(c1 % 4 == 1)
                     {
                        card_suit = suits[1];
                     }

                 else if(c1 % 4 == 2)
                     {
                        card_suit = suits[2];
                     }

                 else if(c1 % 4 == 3)
                     {
                        card_suit = suits[3];
                     }
            System.out.println("Your 1st card is: " +card_rank +" of " +card_suit);
            System.out.println("Your 2nd card is: " +card_rank +" of " +card_suit);
```

Comment: Don't hardcode your variables, and avoid using 'global variables', and you won't run into this problem.

Comment: Yes I'm using global variables but I'm not hardcoding my variables. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming c1 and c2 are your randomly generated cards.

In order to make the method reusable, you need to identify variables within your parameters

Ex. Cards_Match(THESE ARE THE PARAMETERS)

So, in order to essentially "copy" the method, you'd need to call an Object or variable (let's say your random card is from an Object "RandomCard") and put that into your paramemters

```
public static void Cards_Match(RandomCard card){...}
```

Then, where you've put c1, replace with the parameter version "card"

This allows re-usability of the method. Such that you can reuse this method without any limit.

If you have any more questions, ask away!

Comment: I saw this in someone's code online, so my question is how do you compare which is greater or higher in the cards in this for loop:

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
   String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
   System.out.println("You have the " + rank + " of " + suit);
   
   }
  }

Comment: Well here's the second part of a method, returning a variable. Depending on what rank you've given a particular card, you can return a variable (Let's say you're ranking it with an int). So, in terms of card ranking, however you want to set it up where King is a 12 and Ace is a 0, you can return that variable through the method. 

Ex. public static int Cards_Match(RandomCard card){
...
return rankofcard; 
}

So, what you can do now is store the value of the method in an integer and do this with the other random card.

Now you have two ints, you can compare easily from there on.